# What to do to make work button with SpeedDial?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a problem with adding options after expanding a button(app has `bottomAppBar` and `FloatingAction`).

The button works, but when I go to options and want to go to the EditDogScreen page, it does not take me there.The whole thing has been added to the `buttonBar`, will such a reference work? and how to change it.

I am using **`SpeedDial`** Widget for **FAB**

```
 SpeedDial buildSpeedDial() {
   return SpeedDial(
    animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
    animatedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 22.0),
      // child: Icon(Icons.add),
  onOpen: () => print('OPENING DIAL'),
  onClose: () => print('DIAL CLOSED'),
  visible: dialVisible,
  curve: Curves.bounceIn,
  children: [
    **SpeedDialChild(
      label: 'First',
      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () async {
          await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(EditDogScreen.id);
          await backend.getDogs();
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
        ),
      ),
    ),**
    SpeedDialChild(
      child: Icon(Icons.brush, color: Colors.white),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      onTap: () => print('SECOND CHILD'),
      label: 'Second Child',
      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
      labelBackgroundColor: Colors.green,
    ),
    SpeedDialChild(
      child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_voice, color: Colors.white),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      onTap: () => print('THIRD CHILD'),
      labelWidget: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
        child: Text('Custom Label Widget'),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
 }


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
   //  stable top bar for all screens with bottombar
       appBar: AppBar(
    leading: null,
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WelcomeScreen()));
             }),
        ],
      ),

  body: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],
  bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.7),
    color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
    index: _selectedPage,
    buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
    // backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
    animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    onTap: (int index) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedPage = index;
      });
      },
    letIndexChange: (index) => true,
    items: <Widget>[
      Icon(Icons.home, size: 30),
      Icon(Icons.list, size: 30),
      **buildSpeedDial(),**
      Icon(Icons.call_split, size: 30),
      Icon(Icons.perm_identity, size: 30),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: What's the value for `EditDogScreen.id` ?

Comment: EditDogScreen.id takes you to the page with the form to add a dog.

Comment: It's this part that doesn't work right ? Are you sure it's not null ? Did you try with default value ?

Comment: yes, it works fine, so it is a SpeedDial issue.When clicked it doesn't even show any error, it just doesn't work

Comment: Do U think this part is ok? 
**SpeedDialChild(
      label: 'First',
      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onLongPress: () async {
          await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(EditDogScreen.id);
          await backend.getDogs();
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
        ),
      ),
    ),**